# How to split a complex controller into multiple controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Right now I'm working on a project and this controller is getting out of control, but I really don't know how to split it. It has about 400 variables that are very coupled with the $scope.

I did try to group the variables into 5 panels, so I could split the controller later. My objective was: one controller per panel. The problem is that one of the panels has a button that sends all the variables to the server with $http, also when some variables in that panel change, it updates (events) multiple variables in other panels.

[image]

So basically, the panels are still very coupled by events. An event in Panel A can refresh Panels B, C, and D, and an event in panel B can refresh Panels D and E. By refresh I mean modify the view and variables.

I read how to solve the data part, using services to share data between controllers... but this creates a problem with the events because variables inside services are not tied to a $scope, so I'd have to use an observer pattern to notify all the interested Panels when the variables are modiffied in the services, which I feel kinda defeats the purpose of MVC (not sure about this).

**The controller is too big and complex to share it, I'm sorry**, but I just wanted to ask in case someone came across this problem in the past:

**How can I split a very big controller that is very coupled to the $scope because of variables (data), with those variables very coupled by events ($scope digest cycle)?**

Comment: This is a pretty complex thing to describe how to do here, and will probably end up being too broad to be answerable, but I am willing to try to offer some advice in [chat]....

Comment: Awesome, how can we chat?

Comment: I am in the [AngularJs room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63378/angularjs) right now